# The type 'ViewPager' exists in 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI' and in 'Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-viewpager

Update the Core.UI Nugets from 24.x.x to 28.0.x and I get this error, I already removed bin and obj, debug and clean the project, as well as update other Nugets and nothing solves this error message for me.

> Error CS0433 The type 'ViewPager' exists in
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture =
>   neutral, PublicKeyToken = null' and in
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager, Version = 1.0.0.0 , Culture =
>   neutral, PublicKeyToken = null '

Comment: Did you update both Nuget packages to the latest version?

Comment: Please update `Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager` to  the `28.0.x`. For example, If you update `Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI ` to `28.0.0.3`, please update `Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager` to the `28.0.0.3` as well.

Comment: That I did, including all related packages, already solved the problem, what I had to do was uninstall each package with the command 'Uinstall-Package NAME_PACKAGE -Force' and reinstall it

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please post your comment to answer and accept it, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did, including all related packages, already solved the problem, what I had to do was uninstall each package with the command 'Uinstall-Package NAME_PACKAGE -Force' and reinstall it